# Using a variable for a hash key

Tags: hash

I am trying to use a lookup table technique I saw in a recent Craft Link List post, but getting errors.

The general objective is to auto-generate button text from an array of possibilities using a Matrix block type as a key. Here is my code:

```
    {% set buttonText = {
    "video" : "Watch the Video",
    "podcast" : "Listen Now",
    "externalLink" : "Visit Site",
    }   
%}


{# resource is a Matrix fieldtye #}
{% set resources = entry.resource.all() %}
{% for block in resources %}
    {% set text = buttonText[(block.type)] %}
    <div>
        <h2>{{ block.heading }}</h2>
        <p>{{ block.description }}</p>
        <a href="#" class="button">{{ text }}</a>
    </div>  
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is trying to figure out how to use variable as a key in this statement: set text = buttonText[(block.type)], where buttonText is the array and block.type is the key. The value of block.type is correct and matches the key in the array, so I am guessing the syntax is wrong, but can't get it figured out.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: How about `attribute` function? More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38771801/10964722

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example isn't working because `block.type` is actually a shorthand for `block.type.handle`. Use the latter instead and it should work. You can tell this is the case by dumping out `block.type` - it's not a simple string, it's a great big object.

`buttonText[block.type.handle]`

Comment: thanks again, James!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @james smith, that did the trick!

Revised code:

```
        {% set buttonText = {
    "video" : "Watch the Video",
    "podcast" : "Listen Now",
    "externalLink" : "Visit Site",
    }   
%}


{# resource is a Matrix fieldtye #}
{% set resources = entry.resource.all() %}
{% for block in resources %}
    {% set text = buttonText[(block.type.handle)] %}
    <div>
        <h2>{{ block.heading }}</h2>
        <p>{{ block.description }}</p>
        <a href="#" class="button">{{ text }}</a>
    </div>  
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: good stuff... if you could accept my answer instead of adding your own, that would be appreciated!